# Layout Template - Flexbox

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I'm pretty new to flex-box but feel as though I understand it quite well. However, I can not seem to grasp this layout I'm currently working on, I have the correct sizes for the images as I want them.

I'm using this in conjunction with Flexbox properties. My thought process behind it was to have a navigation bar, 100% width. 1 div with 3 div's inside and set the outer div to flex-direction: row; etc... then repeat this step with another set of 3 divs inside a div.

It seems to work on large browsers, however as I'm scaling/resizing the window width ways, the images just become smaller and smaller. This is what I want but I also want it full size in relation to the window.

First of all, I'm not even sure if this possible, but I have tried various different attempts to get it too work and I'm struggling to come up with a solution.

I did think about using media queries to change the layout for various different screen sizes but seems such a laborious process (I'm not lazy, but there must be a more intuitive way to do this as mentioned above).

First Image looks good on a browser above 1600px Height (had to scale image down that's why looks slightly stretched);
[image]

But anything below that it start's showing whitespace;
[image]

```
<body>
<div layout="column" layout-fill>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button style="font-size: 1.5vw;">
                PORTLAND.&nbsp;<md-icon md-font-icon="reorder" style="color:       white; font-size: 2vw;">reorder</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
</div>

<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-start;     flex-wrap: nowrap; height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 0; overflow-y: hidden;     ">
    <div style="height: 50%; width: 25%; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <img class="resize" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" ng-    src="/assets/01_TILE.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="height: 50%; width: 25%; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <img class="resize" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" ng-    src="/assets/02_TILE.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="height: 50%; width: 50%; flex-wrap: nowrap;">
        <img class="resize" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" ng-    src="/assets/03_TILE.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-start;     height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 0;">
    <div style="height: 50%; width: 50%;">
        <img style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" ng-src="/assets/04_TILE.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="height: 50%; width: 25%;">
        <img style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" ng-src="/assets/05_TILE.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="height: 50%; width: 25%;">
        <img style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" ng-src="/assets/06_TILE.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have posted most of my css (inline so I could put up a question) If you haver any questions or need more code let me know and I'll post it up.

Any help would be great as I'm stumped for a solution.

Kind regards,

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Angular Material? If yes, Flexbox its already included: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction

Comment: Hey Javier, yes I'm using Angular-material. I know it includes flex-box. Still don't know how to make this layout work though.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML-Code I miss the `<md-toolbar>`tag
Im not the biggest expert in angular material, to adjust you have to read the documentation:https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children
As I understand you want two rows each with 50% height of the screen.
HTML-Code:

```
<div layout="row">
  <div flex="25"> 
  </div>
  <div flex="25">
  </div>
  <div flex="50">
  </div>
</div>
<div layout="row">
  <div flex="50">
  </div>
  <div flex="25">
  </div>
  <div flex="25">
  </div>
</div>
```

In your CSS-Code add this:

```
div.layout-row {
    height:50%;
}
```

It makes your rows take 50% of the screen, I hope it helps.